# Check inputs with type checkbox with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've been play around with spring-boot and thymeleaf; I'm trying to do a form where I will list numbers and the user will select them; however I would like to "checked" the third element (when equals 3) and I cannot see that the input is checked.

I don't have problems loading the information and display the checkboxes, the problem came when I want to check one of them by default when the page loads.

I need some help identifying what it should be the issue or if it is a bug with th:checked property.

I have this in the controller

```
@ModelAttribute("allFeatures")
public List<Integer> populateFeatures() {
    return  Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

Here is the html code

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="feat : ${allFeatures}">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{features}" th:value="${feat}" th:checked="${feat == 3}"></input>
        <label th:for="${#ids.prev('features')}" th:text="${'seedstarter.feature.' + feat}">Electric Heating</label>
    </li>
    <li th:remove="all">
        <input id="removed1" type="checkbox"/> <label for="removed1">Turf</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with another syntax : <... th:checked="${feat} == 3"> ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `th:checked` and avoid `th:field` and include `'name'` attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" th:checked="${feat} == 3" name="features"></input>
```

**Extra Comment**

But the proper way will be to avoid `th:checked` and `'name'` attributed and stick to the `th:field`. But in that case you have to make sure that you initialize the model attribute `"features"` in the controller before posting it to the view. Here you can define which checkbox to get checked by default from the controller itself.

But your situation seems a bit tricky as you want to display the dynamic list of checkboxes. So I prefer the first solution.

Comment: Thanks Faraj, your first option works!!! :)

Here is the code just to explain:
<input type="checkbox" th:checked="${feat} == 3" th:name="features"></input>

And "features" is the name of variable where I need to submit the result.

Comment: This worked for me at first try. At FIRST TRY! Thanks!